# Раскраска AVL-дерева в красно-чёрное дерево

Tags: структуры-данных

Всегда ли можно раскрасить AVL-дерево так, чтобы получилось красно-чёрное дерево?

Comment: а почему нет? вершины нечетного уровня одним цветом, чётного другим.

Comment: @pavel , рассмотрим такое дерево: 
                 Ч(a)
         K(a, b)             K(a, c)
Ч(b, d)              Ч(b,f)

Оно AVL, но не красно-чёрное, так как нет сбалансированности по черным вершинам. (первая буква -- буква предка, вторая -- своя)